# Finding "Pairs" in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a time-tracking excel spread-sheet. The current data headers I have look like this:

- `Timestamp | Name | Task | TaskUniqueID | Start / Stop ?`

So basically the user just needs to scan the task unique ID, which automatically lists what task it is (so say all my QR codes are TASKA-UniqueID or TASKB-UniqueID). Then the user selects whether they started or stopped.
I want excelt o automatically find the UniqueID that matches (so each unique ID should have a start and a stop row) and then calculate the time difference between these entries. Is that possible with excel or am I going to have to dive into VBA?
So an example of a couple of rows (Note, normally they wouldnt be back-to-back):

```
06/11/2019 08:38:41 John Smith  Power Box - PWR PWR-051 Start
06/11/2019 08:58:38 John Smith  Power Box - PWR PWR-051 Stop
```

Where the Unique id is "PWR-051", which auto-fills the "Task" as "Power box - PWR"
My question is if it is possible in excel to find "pairs" of values and calculate their difference, something like a VLOOKUP, where you lookup the START and the STOP time and then take their respective timestamp and subtract them

Comment: Sounds like a neat project but why are you telling us about it? ;-)  Is there some specific part of this which is giving you problems, and if Yes what is that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! With the description, you will need some VBA code. Anyhow, it seems a little bit unclear

Comment: Sorry, My question is if it is possible in excel to find "pairs" of values and calculate their difference, something like a VLOOKUP, where you lookup the START and the STOP time and then take their respective timestamp and subtract them

Comment: any luck on the tryout ?

Answer (score 0):

Idea : extract the date from start, then extract the date from stop, then find the difference.

Assuming Timestamp is column A, TaskUniqueID is column D, and Start / Stop is column E. Put the interested Task in G1 and TaskUniqueID in H1, then this in G2 :

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,INDEX((G1=C:C)*(H1=D:D)*("Start"=E:E),0,1),0))
```

also this in G3 :

```
=index(A:A,match(1,index((G1=C:C)*(H1=D:D)*("Stop"=E:E),0,1),0))
```

lastly in G4 :

```
=G3-G2
```

[reference](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria)